# Projective line $P_{1}$ as bivariate family

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

Is a projective line $P_{1}$ (brought about by 2 projective points in projective space $P_{n}$ ) a bivariate parametric family?

The aim of the question is to get the concept of a basis in a n-dimensional projective space as a n+1 linearly independent set of projective points and, moreover, the issue of a n+2 point which brings about a "normalization" of those of the former basis-set (that is, the setting of a fixed position of the points within the set, relatively to the quotient space; all this is following a book by Santaló "Projective geometry" (1966)).

Thanks

Comment: Go to my profile and read the single question that I've ever posted here on MO. The question, the linked notes by Michael Artin, and the answer should clear things up.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll take a look!! Greetings